# How do you sandbox cookies between prod, staging and dev environments?

Tags: security, cookies

We have several web applications across multiple subdomains, app1.company.com, app2.company.com.. Additionally, we have multiple environments, prod, staging, dev1, dev2

Each environment has all of it's services use -ENV at the end of the app name to distinguish it from the others. For example

- app1.company.com
- app2.company.com
- app1-staging.company.com
- app2-staging.company.com
- app1-dev1.company.com
- app2-dev1.company.com

This would not be an issue except that we want to start sharing cookies from within an environment. This would mean that cookies would have to have their domain set to .company.com. Which would break our sandboxing. The alternative would be to prefix the environment to cookie names, but that also seems like a kludge, and doesn't provide real security.

So the question is how do people set up their prod, staging and dev environments so that cookies are sandboxed from each other.

Answer (score 5):

Use different domains. You have correctly pointed out that setting the cookie domain to just 'company.com' would share them over all domains and not just some.

You could change the code to set/listen for different cookies in different environments, but that could still make debugging / diagnostics hard if you have lots of spurious cookies in your requests.

So use different domains like:

```
app1.company.com  cookiedomain=.company.com
app2.company.com

app1.staging-company.com  cookiedomain=.staging-company.com
app2.staging-company.com

app1.dev-company.com      cookiedomain=.dev-company.com
app2.dev-company.com
```

Setting up additional domains is easy, you may have an extra SSL certificate cost, but it would not normally be significant. The '.' before the domain set in the cookie is important.

Comment: We considered this, but it doesn't allow us to easily spin up an additional instance because it requires registering another domain. I suppose we could simply add it internally, and create an internal CA, but we were hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Doing some research, and I *think* that current RFCs state that so long as you specify the domain, even without the dot, it still gets treated as the dot. However, if you don't specify the domain, it defaults to the non-dotted version and doesn't get promoted to the dot. (So, the dot shouldn't be important, so long as the domain is manually set. That said, I think it's clearer).

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any viable solution. However, having different names for each cookie seem to work.

If you have user token, then storing it as user-staging, user-prod would work when reading the cookies, however, it is annoying to handle them in multiple places for multiple cookies.